# PostgreSQL for running Tests (Durability is not important)

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-performance

Our Django tests are getting slow, and a lot of time is spend in `cursor.execue()`.

There are roughly two ways now: Rewrite the tests to mock the ORM, or make PostgreSQL faster.

This question is about "make PostgreSQL faster".

What can I do to improve PostgreSQL speed if D (Durability) of ACID is not important. Everything could be kept in RAM.

Constraint: This question is about what you can do without modifying the Django/Python/SQL code.

Comment: As Laurenz pointed out, query tuning generally yields the biggest gains in performance by far. If you provide some example queries, their `EXPLAIN ANALYZE`, and the database schema, likely we can recommend ways to improve them.

Comment: @J.D. the test suite creates several thousand DB queries. All of them are fast. There are no missing indexes.

Comment: I never said anything about missing indexes, rather their **execution plans** might tell of ways to improve their performance (either through tuning, architecting, or even instance changes as you're asking about) and *fast* is a subjective term. If your queries were perfectly fast then you wouldn't have this question on how to "*make PostgreSQL faster*".

Comment: @J.D. I would like to stick to this: This question is about what you can do without modifying the Django/Python/SQL code. I know that there are thousand other ways, but let's focus on this topic here.

Comment: Then the suggestions that Laurenz made are about the extent of what you can do, you can give those a try.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- use `UNLOGGED` tables throughout
- set `shared_buffers` big enough to contain the whole database
- if you have bigger queries, increase `work_mem`
- have enough RAM to contain `shared_buffers` plus `work_mem` times the number of client connections

Typically, you can gain most by tuning the queries that use most of the time.

Comment: If the data isn't important, turning off `fsync` will probably speed up things as well

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name For unlogged tables that won't make much difference.

Comment: But the unlogged tables require changing the SQL scripts that setup the database, whereas turning off fsync requires no changes to the schema migration scripts

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name True. But then I'd set `synchronous_commit = off` rather than the dreaded `fsync`. Bypassing WAL altogether with unlogged table should perform best of all.

Comment: I love PG, since the docs are great. Now I found an official page which exactly this topic https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/non-durability.html

Comment: If you don't want to modify the table creation script, you can add a SQL script with ALTER TABLE SET UNLOGGED on your test tables and only execute it when testing.